# scheme continuation inside a for-each

Tags: foreach, scheme, continuations, callcc

I'm currently studying Scheme for a course at my university, while looking at some exercises I got stuck on this particular one.
Professor has yet to answer my previous mails therefore I have more chances to receive an answer here faster.

Given this code

```
(define (list-iter-cc lst)
  (call/cc 
    (lambda (return) 
      (for-each               
          (lambda (x)
            (call/cc (lambda (next-step)
                       (return (cons x next-step))))) 
          lst)
     'end)))
```

I have to use it to write the `iter` macro whose syntax is

```
(iter <a variable symbol> in <a list> <code>)
```

example:

```
(iter x in '(1 2 3) 
    (display x)
    (newline))
```

Since I couldn't understand `list-iter-cc` i went to see the solution, which i don't understand as well. The solution:

```
(define-syntax iter2
  (syntax-rules (-> in)
    ((_ var in lst code ...)
     (let loop ((head (list-iter-cc lst)))
       (unless (eq? head 'end)
         (let ((var (car head)))
           code ... 
           (loop ((cdr head)))))))))
```

To unravel the macro I tried writing the following

```
> (define head (list-iter-cc '(1 2 3 4)))
> head
'(1 . #<continuation>)
> (let ( (var (car head))) (display var))
1
> (define head2 (cdr head))
> (let ( (var2 (car head2)) ) (display var2))
Xxx X car: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: #<continuation>
>
```

which is exactly what I thought would happen.

`list-iter-cc`'s return continuation is called at the first iteration of the for-each inside the first lambda, returning with `cons x next-step`.
`x` is the first element of the list and `next-step` is a continuation.

1). what is the content of `next-step`? the following iteration of the `for-each`? how can it evaluate to `'end` after the last iteration?

2). assuming that in the macro `head (list-iter-cc lst)` is `'(1 . #<continuation>)` , the *car* is `1` and it gets displayed, but after looping over its *cdr*, `var (car head)` will be the *car* of the continuation! how can it possibly evaluate to `2` and then `3` and then `'end`, and why this does not happen in the code I tried writing to understand it?

Any help would be appreciated, especially one that could guide me step by step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can re-write it as

```
(define list-iter-cc 
  (lambda (lst)
    (call/cc 
      (lambda (return) 
        (for-each               
            (lambda (x)
              (call/cc (lambda (next-step)
                         (return (cons x next-step))))) 
            lst)
        'end))))
```

So it's a lambda function, with a parameter named `lst`. When this function is called, `lst` is set up to hold the actual argument of the function call, as usual. Then, `call/cc` sets up the continuation named `return` to hold the current continuation ... which is what? At this point, the *next-thing-to-do* is just to return a value to the `list-iter-cc`'s caller.

This means, calling `(return a)` will return the value of `a` immediately to `list-iter-cc`'s caller, as if the function `list-iter-cc` finished up its calculations.

Now,

```
        (for-each               
            (lambda (x)
              (call/cc (lambda (next-step)
                         (return (cons x next-step))))) 
            lst)
```

is entered. It calls its lambda argument for each element in a list `lst`, which consequently gets the name `x`.

So, for the very fist `x` in a `lst`, what happens?

```
              (call/cc (lambda (next-step)
                         (return (cons x next-step))))
```

is called. I.e. it sets up `next-step` to hold the *current* continuation and *returns*  from the whole function `list-iter-cc` at once!

What does it return? The pair `(x . <next-step>)`. And *what* does it mean to call `(next-step)`? It means to return into the body of `for-each`, which will proceed to the next element in `lst`, *if any*. If not, the loop body of `for-each` is exited, and `'end` is *normally* returned as last expression's value  from the function `list-iter-cc`, which thus finishes its calculations!

So, how can we use it? For example, like this:

```
(define (qq lst)
  (let ([a ;; <<=                    ; control returns here
           (list-iter-cc lst)])
    (unless (eq? a 'end)             ; if it's not past-last-element
       (let ([val (car a)])          ; take the actual value
         (display val)               ; use it
         (newline)
         ((cdr a))))))               ; run the `next-step` continuation
```

When the continuation in `(cdr a)` is run, the control jumps back to `list-iter-cc`'s call site. Remember, "the *next-thing-to-do*" was "just to return a value to the `list-iter-cc`'s caller"? The outer `let`'s body is then re-entered with the next value from the list.

This needs to be translated to a macro then, which should be straightforward.

I notice your prof used *named loop* there, and the macro calls `(loop ((cdr a)))`. The continuation does not return its value though, and so the next iteration of `loop` is not entered *because of the call to `loop`*. The control *jumps* as part of the continuation, as seen in my sample function (it worked, when I tested it in DrRacket).

---

*update:*  Regarding your transcript, `head2` is already a `#<continuation>`, it doesn't have a `car` – it is not a `pair?`. Instead, see the following:

```
> (define head #| <<= |# (list-iter-cc '(1 2 3 4)))   ; control returns here
> head
'(1 . #<continuation>)
> (let ( (var (car head))) (display var))             ; your code
1
> ((cdr head))                                        ; this is how we run it!
> head
'(2 . #<continuation>)
>
```

What? Have you seen what just happened? `head` got redefined! And again,

```
> ((cdr head))
> head
'(3 . #<continuation>)
>
```

Why? Because running a continuation means the control returns to its call site – which, here, means *"define a variable `head` to hold the supplied value, and return to the REPL"*.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I more or less had guessed what was happening but when I tried to verify it with my transcript it didn't worked, and your update showed me WHY! I should have just called and run the continuation again with `((cdr head))` and head would have acquired the new value. Very clever! May I ask you what you mean by `I notice your prof used  [...]` it seems to me that by calling `(loop ( (cdr head) ) )` we are not only passing the continuation to the next iteration but we are executing it as well. Am I correct?

Comment: continuations do not return, so I tried to say "run" instead of "is called" to hint at that fact. Calling `(loop (function call))` calls `(function call)`, receives the result from it, then passes it to the next iteration of `loop`. Here, `(cdr a)` is "called" nay "run". It won't *ever* return a value, because continuations *jump*; they *return into* their own destination, not the syntactic call that triggered their *running*. Notice I wrote simply `((cdr a))` and it then re-enters the loop body. I didn't use `(loop ((cdr a)))` like in your post. (I assumed your professor gave you this code).

Comment: so we are definitely ***not*** passing the continuation to anywhere. this is ***not*** a "continuation"-passing style where "continuations" are just regular functions, and not true full-blown continuations. Confusing naming, right? I try calling them "contingency-functions" instead. --- here, we have a ***true*** continuation, which *runs*, it is not "called" because it does not return to its caller -- a true continuation returns to *its* context, its definition place. --- and you're most welcome!