# Continuations in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, continuations, callcc

Here is the code:

```
(define (first lst) 
  (call/cc (lambda (exit)
             (for-each
              (lambda (x)
                (call/cc (lambda (nested)
                           (exit (cons x nested)))))
              lst))))

(define (main)
  (let ((x (first '(h e l l o))))
    (when (cons? x)
      (display (car x))
      ((cdr x)))))
```

This code simply print: hello. I don't understand what happens when we do:

```
((cdr x))
```

To be precise, what Scheme exactly does when we call the last expression. I mean that I understand that we go back in the nested call/cc but why every time it takes a new character instead that the older one?

I was expecting and infinite printing of the character "h": hhhhhhh...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It so happens that I answered this already, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46959681/849891).